# Python , SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

на сайте Microsoft есть пример подключения к БД.

```
    import pyodbc 
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Но у меня используется аутентефикация ОС и нет пароля.
Как изменить мне код чтоб происходил вход в БД
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/q/16515420/10941639.

Answer (score 0):

Я в python использую авторизацию SQL сервера. Входить на сервер могу с помощью учетной записи Windows и с помощью учетной записи SQL

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-8EKCG28\RUSGUARD;DATABASE=RUSGUARDDB;UID=sa;PWD=123')
```